# MySQL: Select via association

Tags: mysql, sql, select, associations

I have the following MySQL tables:

**Table `company`** containg the following attributes (about 250 rows):

- id_cpy (int)
- name_cpy (varchar)
- xxx_cpy (more company attributes)

**Table `event`** containg the following attributes (about 20 rows):

- id_evt (int)
- name_evt (varchar)
- xxx_evt ((more event attributes)

**Cross table `cpy_evt`** (about 550 rows) defines what company is involved in what event. The table contains one row per association between a company and an event. The table contains the following attributes:

- id_crs
- id_cpy_crs
- id_evt_crs

Due to my limited SQL knowledge I have the following questions.

How can I select:

1. All companies (all attributes) that are involved in event A
2. All companies that are involved in event A AND event B
3. All companies that are involved in event A OR event B
4. All companies that are not involved in any event

Thanks a lot for your help!
Hannes

Comment: this is not a coding service .. you should at least post a single question  ..not a list of desiderata  ...

Comment: Did you try anything? (Hint: JOIN). At least post the name of your "cross table".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. All companies (all attributes) that are involved in event A

Without knowing your data, I would go for the safer approach to avoid potential duplicates : an EXISTS condition with a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT c.*
FROM company c
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM company_event ce
    INNER JOIN event e ON e.name_evt = 'A' AND e.id_evt = ce.id_evt_crs
    WHERE ce.id_cpy_crs = c.id_cpy
)
```

> 2. All companies that are involved in event A AND event B

You can add an additional EXISTS condition :

```
SELECT c.*
FROM company c
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM company_event ce
    INNER JOIN event e ON e.name_evt = 'A' AND e.id_evt = ce.id_evt_crs
    WHERE ce.id_cpy_crs = c.id_cpy
)
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM company_event ce
    INNER JOIN event e ON e.name_evt = 'B' AND e.id_evt = ce.id_evt_crs
    WHERE ce.id_cpy_crs = c.id_cpy
)
```

> 3. All companies that are involved in event A OR event B

Change the equality condition on event name to an IN condition.

```
SELECT c.*
FROM company c
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM company_event ce
    INNER JOIN event e ON e.name_evt IN ('A', 'B') AND e.id_evt = ce.id_evt_crs
    WHERE ce.id_cpy_crs = c.id_cpy
)
```

> 4. All companies that are not involved in any event

This simplifies the subquery, since we do not need to join the event table.

```
SELECT c.*
FROM company c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM company_event ce
    WHERE ce.id_cpy_crs = c.id_cpy
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @GMB; I was not aware of the EXISTS functionality in SQL.